# Indirectly casting long[] to ulong[] via Array gives differnt Types (GetType vs. is ulong[])

Tags: c#, arrays, casting

I dont under stand why `d is long[]` and `d is ulong[]` is giving `true`. Any hints on that why this is working?
And a second question, why isn't a cast to `double[]` working?

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        long[] a = new Int64[10];
        ulong[] b = (ulong[]) (Array) a;
        
        Array d;
        
        // not allowed
        // double[] c = (double[]) (Array) a;
        
        a[0] = -5;
        
        // check types of a
        d = a;
        Console.WriteLine("d.GetType() {0}", d.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("a.GetType() {0}", a.GetType());
        if(d is ulong[])
            Console.WriteLine("{0}","d is ulong[]");
        if(d is long[])
            Console.WriteLine("{0}","d is long[]");
        if(a is ulong[])
            Console.WriteLine("{0}","a is ulong[]");
        if(a is long[])
            Console.WriteLine("{0}","a is long[]");
        
        // check types of b
        d = b;
        Console.WriteLine("d.GetType() {0}", d.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("b.GetType() {0}", b.GetType());
        if(d is long[])
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", "d is long[]");
        if(d is ulong[])
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", "d is ulong[]");
        if(b is long[])
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", "b is long[]");
        if(b is ulong[])
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", "b is ulong[]");
        
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", a[0], b[0]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
d.GetType() System.Int64[]
a.GetType() System.Int64[]
d is ulong[]
d is long[]
a is long[]
d.GetType() System.Int64[]
b.GetType() System.Int64[]
d is long[]
d is ulong[]
b is ulong[]
-5 18446744073709551611
```

Comment: *"The `E is T` expression returns `true` if the result of `E` is non-null and can be converted to type `T` by a reference conversion, a boxing conversion, or an unboxing conversion; otherwise, it returns `false`."* -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator

Comment: But why can you do that with the indirect cast but not directly, e.g. ```(ulong[]) long[]``` and why is it not possible for a ```double[]```?

Comment: ok, a double is a struct, but why is the first thingy working via ```Array```

Comment: I don't know the exact reasons, but going from `long` to `ulong` is a lossy type conversion.  I can only assume that, when you cast to `Array` first, C# no longer knows that.  Unlike `long` and `ulong`, `ulong` and `double` don't have the same data representation under the hood.